# Clean two form fields together

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a custum signup form for my page, and Im trying to create a clean method that could check if user excist when they try to sign up. If they excist, they should not see any warnings.

My model:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    external_reference = models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

My clean method:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data['email']
    external_reference = self.cleaned_data['external_reference']
    if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        try:
            #User exist, use form to update user
            Profile.objects.get(external_reference=external_reference, user__email=email)
            return email
        except Profile.DoesNotExist:    
            raise forms.ValidationError(u'Email in use')

    return email
```

I get this error: `KeyError: 'external_reference'`

Maybe it only possible to "clean" one field at the time? Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Such things should be done in `clean()` method of form than a field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Form and field validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/validation/) in the official docs in the *Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other* section.

As Rohan commented you should clean fields that depend on each other in the clean() method.

When *clean_email* is called *external_reference* hasn't been cleaned yet and there for it isn't in *self.cleaned_data* yet (hence the KeyError).

```py
def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(Class, self.clean)
    email = cleaned_data.get('email')
    external_reference = cleaned_data.get('external_reference')
    if email and external_reference:
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            try:
                #User exists, use form to update user
                Profile.objects.get(external_reference=external_reference, user__email=email)
            except Profile.DoesNotExist:
                self.add_error('email', 'Email in use')

    return cleaned_data
```

Remember to use *get* on *cleaned_data* to get *email* and *external_reference* and check if they exist because if their individual *clean_field* methods raised validation errors then they would not be in *cleaned_data* and you would get a KeyError once again.

PS: If you are on django version prior to 1.7 use *self._errors['email'] = self.error_class(['Email in use'])* instead of *self.add_error*.